# How to use Excel VBA to compare two worksheets and keep rows with unique IDs

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I am trying to use Excel and VBA to query new values to a worksheet, run some checks and calculations on the query data and archive the rows that meet a certain criteria.  I have the current worksheet cross referenced to an archive worksheet and any rows that are not already in the archived worksheet are copied to it.  I was using two for loops to iterate through IDs in each worksheet but as I have learned like everybody before me that once the row numbers become significant the macro becomes unwieldingly slow.  I have tried using range examples with variants but can only get comparisons between columns to return column values not the whole row.

A sample of my loop code is as follows:

```
Dim ALastRow As Long, ALastCol As Long
With ActiveSheet
    ALastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ALastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Dim iRow2 As Integer, counter As Integer, IDrow As Integer, match As Integer
Dim This_Sheet4 As Worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Activate
Set This_Sheet4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Archive)

counter = 1
IDrow = 5
For iRow = 2 To LastRow2
    match = 0
    For iRow2 = 2 To ALastRow
        If match = 0 Then
            If iRow2 = ALastRow Then
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Cells(iRow, 12).Value > 1.11111111111111E-02 Then
                            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Cells(iRow, IDrow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Archive).Cells(iRow2, IDrow).Value Then
                            match = 1
                            Else
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Archive).Rows(ALastRow + counter)
                            counter = counter + 1
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Archive).Activate
                            Cells(iRow2, 1).Select
                            End If
                        End If
                Else
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Cells(iRow, IDrow).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Archive).Cells(iRow2, IDrow).Value Then
                    match = 1
                    Else
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(QueryArray(i, 1)).Activate
                    Cells(iRow, 1).Select
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next iRow2
    Next iRow
Next
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with mysql.  Please remove that tag.

Comment: Have you tried stacking one on top of the other and using *Remove Duplicates*?

Comment: @RashminJaviya Regarding your change to my suggested edit, please see [this discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/3725745) about removing salutations and similar content from posts.

Comment: @RashminJaviya: "Thanks in advance" is fluff that should be removed from questions, you shouldn't have edited the edit suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add a column to your current worksheet data (I hide it so no one changes it!), you could simply have the macro fill in a value - "x", timestamp, etc - in this "Archived" column after it has archived the row.  Then when you run the macro to archive columns that meet the appropriate criteria, you can either

1) filter the table to Criteria1:=vbNullString to get only the un-archived rows and work with myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Example:

```
Dim currentSheet as Worksheet
Dim TblLength as long
Dim Table as string

Table = "TableName"
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet

With currentSheet.Range(Table)
   TblLength = .Columns(1).Rows.Count
   'clear any existing filters
   .AutoFilter  

   'set new filters
   .AutoFilter Field:=currentSheet.Range(Table & "[Transferred]").Column, Criteria1:=vbNullString
End With

If currentSheet.Range("A1:A" & TblLength + 1).Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
  'make sure we have visible rows
  Set CopyRange = currentSheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
  'other code
End If
```

or

2) loop through all rows in the current worksheet and test If Range("Table[Archived]")(Row) = vbNullString to tell whether or not you have archived it.

Example:

```
For Row = 1 To Range(Table).Rows.Count
   If Range(Table & "[Archived]")(Row) = vbNullString Then
          'your code here
   End if
Next Row
```

Alternatively, you could sort the archiveSheet by one of the columns - for example, if listing securities sales and purchases, by the Cusip column.  You could then have your first loop be through currentSheet, and the first check on the inner loop through archiveSheet tests to see if the cusips match.  That way, once you are past that cusip in archiveSheet, you can exit the loop - still requires a lot of looping, but a little bit less!

Example:

```
archiveSheet.Sort Key1:="Cusip", order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes

For iRow2 = 2 To ALastRow
    match = 0
    'assuming the cusip is in column A...
    myCusip = currentSheet.Range("A" & iRow2).Value
    'we want to know if we've reached it yet
    cusipMatched = false
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow2

        If myCusip = archiveSheet.Range("A" & iRow).Value Then
           cusipMatched = true
           'your code to check if the row matches
        Else
           If cusipMatched Then
              'we've already reached our cusip, so now we are past it
              ' this exits the current For loop and continues on in the outer For loop
              Exit For
           End if
        End if
   Next iRow
Next iRow2
```